When using tailwind along side php, only some classes work. Such as I can use flex flex-col but when I add gap-10 or a margin it does not take
When I apply certain classes to my code. Such as, mt-4, px-3, and gap-10 they have no effect. Other classes such as flex, flex-col, text-2xl do take effect. This is stopping me aligning elements as I wish.
<?php
    
// start php session
session_start();
    
include "../../config/dbConfig.php";
include "../partials/header.php";
?>
    
    
<body class="min-h-screen">
    
    <div class="container mx-auto h-screen">
        <main class="register_btn_container flex flex-col gap-5 items-center justify-center">
            <h1 class="text-5xl font-bold">Register</h1>
            <button type="button" class="bg-primary w-24 text-white shadow-md py-1 flex items-center justify-between m-10"><span class="ml-3">Join Us</span><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right mr-3"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="bg-secondary w-24 text-white shadow-md py-1 flex items-center justify-between "><span class="ml-3">Join Us</span><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right mr-3"></i>
                </button>
            <button type="button" class="bg-primary w-24 text-white shadow-md py-1 flex items-center justify-between "><span class="ml-3">Join Us</span><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right mr-3"></i>
            </button>
        </main>
        <aside class="img_container">hi</aside>
    
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>


Consider checking:

The file that you use the classes in are covered by the content file globs in the Tailwind configuration. If Tailwind does not "see" a class name in the content in scans, it won't generate the CSS rule for it and thus the class name won't work.
For any other CSS that may be conflicting with Tailwind's generated CSS rules.
You have run a Tailwind compilation since adding the classes.
The browser you are viewing the webpage through is using the most up-to-date version of the CSS file. You can use your browser's developer tools to confirm the latest CSS file is being used and not cached. You can also temporarily disable your browser's cache while having the developer tools open.
The values exist for the classes you are trying to use. Certain Tailwind configurations can cause some of the default Tailwind classes to not exist any more, such as by having theme.spacing instead of theme.extend.spacing in your Tailwind configuration.

